# How to create 0 byte orc file

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, orc

Can I create 0 byte ORC file?

I'd like to test

1. if hive can load 0 byte file into external table without exception.
2. if python can read 0 byte orc file without exception.

```py
for filename in glob.glob(orc_path):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        data = orc.ORCFile(file)
```

Is there any way to create ORC file with spark/python/hive or in command line?

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Is a 0-byte ORC file valid? At minimum, there's a section at the end of the file that contains info for parsing the rest of the file. Even if there's no data in the file, that section has size info for other sections and so would have use bytes just to say the rest of the file doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty file you can open in it write mode and close it again without writing anything.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    pass
```